# Dynamically populating nested react-native-collapsible

Tags: react-native, expo, accordion, react-native-collapsible

I need to populate a menu with items from an api request.
I made some sample items; `const items`. Some of the menu items have children, and the children can also have children, so I need to nest several levels of menu items.

I made an `Accordion()` with Collapsible from react-native-collapsible and an `AccordionItem()` for items that have no children.

`function App()` renders the menu items twice. Once by manually adding `Accordion`s and `AccordionItem`s and once by mapping `items[]`. `RootMenuItem()` is called for each top level item and renders that item and its sub-items by recursion.

When manually adding each item it works the way I want it to. I need to populate the menu programatically, but nested accordions rendered by `RootMenuItem()` are misbehaving on android and iOS. When testing in Web on snack.io it seems to be working fine.

Here is a snack with my complete App.js:
https://snack.expo.dev/@dissar/nested-collapsibles

Am I doing something wrong?
Does anybody have any tips for doing this in a better way?

PS: The dynamically rendered items have weird widths when testing on snack.io, but don't worry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have fixed it myself by removing the View on line 46 and 56;

```
function RootMenuItem({item}){
  if(item.children.length > 0) {
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1}} key={item.id}>    // <---- I removed this
        <Accordion item={item} style={styles.menuItemView}>
          {
            item.children.map(child => (
              <View style={{paddingLeft: 18}} key={child.id}>
                <RootMenuItem item={child} style={{paddingLeft: 10}}/>
              </View>
            ))
          }
        </Accordion>
      </View> // <---- Also removed this
    )
  }
  else return (
    <AccordionItem item={item}/>
  )
}
```

Not really sure though why that View made the nested accordions not work as they should. Please let me know if you have the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution without using any 3rd party library. This is completely customised and easy to understand. I used the same format of data as you used.

first of all, we have a component

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(null);
return (
<ScrollView
  style={{ marginTop: 50 }}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
  {arr.map((x, i) => (
    <Item
      key={x.name}
      active={active}
      i={i}
      setActive={setActive}
      child={x.child}
    />
  ))}
</ScrollView>
```

);

then for the list items and their child

```
function Item({ i, active, setActive, child }) {
  const onPress = () => {
    LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
    setActive(i == active ? null : I);
  };
  const [childActive, setChildActive] = useState(null);
  const open = active == I;
  return (
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={onPress} activeOpacity={1}>
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
    <Text>Header - {i + 1}</Text>
    {child.length ? <Text>{open ? 'close' : 'open'}</Text> : null}
  </View>
  {open &&
    child.map((x, i) => {
      if (x.child.length) {
        return (
          <Item
            key={x}
            active={childActive}
            i={i}
            setActive={setChildActive}
            child={x.child}
          />
        );
      }
      return (
        <Text key={x} style={styles.subItem}>
          - SOME DATA
        </Text>
      );
    })}
</TouchableOpacity>
);
}
```

It's a completely dynamic process, you can extend the chain as long as you want. You can also check out the expo to look at its works.
https://snack.expo.dev/@akash0208/forlorn-popsicle